# y intercepts of curve levels

Tags: calculus

I am having a tough time with this homework assignment. We are working with level curves and this whole idea of using the $z$ value is throwing me off a lot. 

I will start with the problem:

Determine the y-intercept(s) of the level curve, where
$f(x,y)=2e^{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ and $z=4$.

I started but setting $4=f(x,y)$ then I solved for $y$ and got $\sqrt{\frac{2ln(2)}{4}-x^2}$ and I tried solving for $y=0$. Can anyone give me any advice on this problem? Is there a similar way to do this? Am I missing a step and is there a better way to think about it? I can't find any help from my teacher or TA. Thank you!

Comment: What trouble did you run into when trying to solve for $x$ at $y=0$?

Comment: well when i set it equal to y=0 I got x=-.589 or sqrt(2ln(2))/2 and this is wrong apparently.

Comment: Oh, I read too fast. You should have set $x=0$ and solved for $y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if $z=4$, $f(x,y)=4$.

Henceforth, $4=2e^{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$. So yes, you were correct to this.

To find the y-intercepts, $x=0$ since the intercepts are solely on the $y$-axis and you already know that $z=4$.

You now have $4=2e^{2\sqrt{y^2}}$ for $x=0,z=4$.

**NOTE:** You cannot solve for the intercepts if $y=0$ because you would be finding the $x$-intercepts instead!

**NOW** you can solve for $y$! :)

Comment: that was it thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome! Welcome to Math SE by the way!